# Can not find this kanji online

Tags: kanji

この漢字は読めない[image]

I guess I also just need to add more words to post this question. Please help if you can read the kanji, and thank you.

Comment: Possibly this one? 〆

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is 不 (fu) in a semi-cursive font.